# Receving a this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: mainLoop is not defined

Tags: javascript

My 9 year old son is learning Javascript. I'm not able to easily help him. He's working on a small project, and can't seem to get past an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: mainLoop is not defined.

This is a great learning opportunity for him. We appreciate any clues as to what's going on in his code that's causing the error. Thanks!

Here's what he's got:

```js
var CANVAS_WIDTH = 800;
var CANVAS_HEIGHT = 400;
var LEFT_ARROW_KEYCODE = 37;
var RIGHT_ARROW_KEYCODE = 39;
//SETUP
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;

document.body.appendChild(canvas);
window.requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
var shapeInfo = {
  squares: {

    square1: {
      x: 10,
      y: 10,
      w: 30,
      h: 30,
      color: 'orange'
    }

  }
};
window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
window.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);

var leftArrowKeyIsPressed = false;
var rightArrowKeyIsPressed = false;
var touchingRightEdge = false;
// SENSORS
function sense() {
  if (shapeInfo.squares.square1.x <= CANVAS_WIDTH - 30) {
    touchingRightEdge = true;
  }
  // PLAYER CONTROLS

  function onKeyDown(event) {

    if (event.keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW_KEYCODE) {
      rightArrowKeyIsPressed = true;
    }

  }

  function onKeyUp(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW_KEYCODE) {
      rightArrowKeyIsPressed = false;
    }

  }


  //MAIN LOOP
  function mainLoop() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
    draw();
  }
  //DRAW
  function draw() {
    c.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
    // Draw the frame
    c.strokeStyle = 'black';
    c.strokeRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
    // Draw square1
    c.fillStyle = shapeInfo.squares.square1.color;
    c.fillRect(shapeInfo.squares.square1.x, shapeInfo.squares.square1.y, shapeInfo.squares.square1.w, shapeInfo.squares.square1.h);
    if (rightArrowKeyIsPressed) {
      if (!touchingRightEdge) {
        shapeInfo.squares.square1.x++;
      }
    }
    if (leftArrowKeyIsPressed) {

      shapeInfo.squares.square1.x--;

    }
    // end
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `mainLoop()` function is defined **inside** the `sense()` function, so it's not visible outside that scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great to hear that your son is learning something as cool as JavaScript. Now as @Pointy pointed out (no pun intended) you are calling `window.requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);` outside the `sense` function which causes the error. The `mainLoop` function does not exist outside `sense`.

The solution to this would to be define your functions globally, in this case meaning:
**not inside another function.**

So prevent doing:

```
function foo() {
  // Do something

  function bar() {
    // Do something else
  }

}

foo() // Do someting
bar() // Uncaught ReferenceError: bar is not defined.
```

Now `bar` only exists within `foo`. Instead do this:

```
function foo() {
  // Do something
}

function bar() {
  // Do something else
}

foo() // Do something
bar() // Do something else
```

Both functions can now be called from the same *scope* (remember this word).

Also in your `mainLoop` function you got to switch some things around. Try to call the `draw` function **first** before you start the `mainLoop` again. JavaScript works from top to bottom. So in the example below it will first `draw` and then start the loop again.

```
function mainLoop() {
  draw();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

You're doing great, kid! Keep it up and come back whenever you want. We'll help you out!

Comment: Thanks so much guys! I shared this with my son, and he was really excited about it. He said: 

"Hey Dad!
It worked! I fixed it! It turns out there was a wrong function closing that I did. I closed my sense function at the end of the code instead of a certain place. 
Now I need to figure out how to do multiple key commands."

Thanks for the fix and the additional lesson. Perfect! Now, he wants to get his square to move using the arrow keys in ALL directions. He can only get it to move one direction with one key press at a time. ;)

Comment: Thanks for sharing you and your son's experience with us. It makes everything worthwhile and is the reason for many of us to do this in our spare time. If he needs any help regarding his current or future projects, then he'll know how to reach us. Have a good one!